# What space are acceleration vectors in?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

Let $M$ be a configuration space(manifold) and $x(t)$ be a curve on $M$.

A velocity vector $\dot{x}(t)$ is in the tangent space $T_{x(t)} M$. Where is an acceleration vector $\ddot{x}(t)$?

Comment: Naturally, an acceleration vector is a point in the double tangent bundle $TTM$. However, if $M$ has a connection on the tangent bundle, then an acceleration vector can be thought of as a point in $TM$.

Comment: Maybe can help [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_(differential_geometry))